# Where can I get a high-quality ADC (audio digitizer) for Arduino?

Tags: audio

Is there a high-quality (32 bit/96,000 kbps) digitizer for Arduino?

Does anybody know where I can find the best options for this?

Comment: 32 bit ADCs are unlikely to exist.  Even at 24 bits on a multilayer PCB designed by an experienced professional the lower bits will only have meaning in a statistical sense as an input to certain types of filtering.  You are unlikely to be able to use even 16 bits to full advantage in an arduino project, so there's no point in looking beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need a bigger board.

(96000000 samples/second) * (32 bits / sample) ~= [3 Gigabits/second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2896000000%20sample%2Fsecond%29%20*%20%2832%20bits%20%2F%20sample%29)

A poor little Arduino Uno only runs at 20MHz and can process 8 bits bytes at a time, so even if it could somehow read and store a byte every cycle, it would still be orders of magnitude too slow for your purposes.

While I guess is might be possible to build a shield with an ultra high speed ADC and on board memory to directly store the captures samples to, you probably would bother making it since the Arduino would struggle to do anything useful with the captured data even after the fact.

The highest quality audio recording shield for Arduino I've seen is a modified [Wav Shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/94?&main_page=product_info&cPath=17_21&products_id=94) that can record 8-bit mono files at 44,100 samples per second using the [waverp library](https://blog.adafruit.com/2009/07/07/waverp-an-arduino-library-for-recording-and-playing-wave-files-on-the-adafruit-wave-shield/).

Answer (score 1):

think 96000kps was most likely a typo. 96ksps or 96000sps is more likely since the title specifies audio. Still a little too much for an Arduino though. You need a chip with I2S and a CODEC chip.

I am working on a project at the moment interfacing a PIC32 to a CODEC for CD quality audio reproduction. The codec I am using (PCM1774) is DAC only, but you can get CODECs in many combinations of ADC and DAC with different numbers of channels in each.

I2S is very similar to SPI but needs some extra facilities that not all chips can provide. Things like:

- High speed flexible base clock at (for example) 256x the sample frequency
- Left/Right framing clock derived from base clock
- DMA for smooth transfer of data

I don't know what offerings Atmel have, but for PIC32 you need one of the more modern chips, such as the PIC32MX1xx/2xx family, PIC32MX470, or for high end work the 200MHz PIC32MZ chips.

The MX1xx/2xx and MZ chips are available in a Arduino-like system called chipKIT which might suit your needs better than small Atmel chips.

The Arduino Due might also be able to do I2C but I won't be able to help you with that since I have relegated my Due to the bittom of my junk pile.